# How do I use a method in a derived python class only if it is defined, with a fallback otherwise?

Tags: python, oop

I have a question about how to structure a class hierarchy and how to think about inheritance in python. Or maybe just about how to make `pylint` happy.

Suppose I have a class that describes how to calculate a certain quantity, and that there's a generic, but slow way of doing this, as well as more specific but faster ways of doing the same. How do I write a class hierarchy that describes this?

As I've described so far, the following should do what I want, just by overriding the `do_stuff` method for the specific cases

```python
class SlowDoer():
    def do_stuff(*args):
        # generic but slow implementation
        ...
        
class ConcreteFastDoer1(SlowDoer):
    def do_stuff(*args):
        # specific but faster implementation
        ...

class ConcreteFastDoer2(SlowDoer):
    def do_stuff(*args):
        # specific but faster implementation
        ...
```

Unfortunately, the fast method and the slow method share a lot of logic, so this feels unsatisfying. In reality, the fast methods can only solve most of the problem, and then they fall back on the slow method for the remainder. So the above approach means writing a lot of the same lines twice, which doesn't feel right.

Instead, I could modify the classes to something like the following, where the fast method is passed

```python
class AbstractDoer():
    def do_stuff(*args, do_stuff_fast=None):
        if do_stuff_fast is not None:
            do_stuff_fast(*args)
            do_stuff_slow(*remainder)
        else:
            do_stuff_slow(*args)
        # generic but slow implementation
        ...

class ConcreteFastDoer(AbstractDoer):
    def do_stuff_fast(*args):
        ...
        
    def do_stuff(*args):
        return super().do_stuff(*args, self.do_stuff_fast)
```

If I do that, my linter complains about the removed argument in `do_stuff`. It's not wrong, and the method could be modified to something along the lines of

```python
    def do_stuff(*args, fast_doer=None):
        if fast_doer is None:
            fast_doer = self.do_stuff_fast
        return super().do_stuff(*args, fast_doer)
```

This is unsatisfying for two reasons:

1. The None check/argument mismatch and its solution is deeply silly: the argument was only added to the base class to let the derived class inject its method, and no caller outside the classes is ever expected to supply it.
2. Overriding the `do_stuff` method has to be done for each of the derived classes, which again creates code repetition without any real information content.

I know I could get around point 2 just by adding an extra layer in my class hierarchy, but I'm looking for solutions  where I don't need to. And point 1 still feels like a strong argument against to me.

Ideally, I would like to do something along the lines of the following: always try to call the fast method, and if that fails, fall back on the slower method:

```python
class AbstractDoer:
    def do_stuff(self, *args):
        try:
            self.do_stuff_fast(*args)
            self.do_stuff_slow(*remainder)
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.do_stuff_slow(*args)

    def do_stuff_slow(self, *args):
        ...

    def do_stuf_fast(self, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class ConcreteDoer(AbstractDoer):
    def do_stuff_fast(self, *args):
        ...
```

But when I do that, my linter (not unreasonably) complains when I create classes which don't override `do_stuff_fast`

This is for a hobby project of a few k LOC, so I have complete freedom to change things, and to play around a bit.

I don't have much practice modelling relationships between base and derived classes, but the last approach certainly seems most intuitive to me. Evidently my linter disagrees.

---

**So my questions are as follows**

1. Is there a small change I can make to either the base or the derived class which can make my last example Good Python™?
2. Alternatively, why is this a bad idea, and how should I structure my classes instead?

Comment: Do you have to use classes here? Or could you use functions?
I know that I am asking this against the question context, but I wanted to know if more possibilities could be taken into account.

Comment: In principle everything could always just be a function :) There's enough (mutable) state involved in the calculations that it's easier for me to reason about when it's encapsulated in a class. But it might  be possible to to keep the mutable state in its own object and make these pure functions just take those objects as parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code...

```py
        try:
            self.do_stuff_fast(*args)
            self.do_stuff_slow(*remainder)
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.do_stuff_slow(*args)
```

...is `remainder` a return value from `do_stuff_fast`? Because if so, it seems like you could get what you want like this:

```py
class AbstractDoer:
    def do_stuff(self, *args):
        remainder = self.do_stuff_fast(*args)
        if remainder:
            self.do_stuff_slow(*remainder)

    def do_stuff_slow(self, *args):
        ...

    # base implementation returns args unmodified
    def do_stuff_fast(self, *args):
        return args

class ConcreteDoer(AbstractDoer):
    # fast implementation returns a subset of args
    def do_stuff_fast(self, *args):
        ...
        return remaining_args
```

No linting errors here.